# ApexCharts using .NET data on Gauge chart

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, apexcharts

I am using ApexCharts for dashboard.I initialize the chart with sample data so I can see it working.  How can i add real time .Net data.How can i resolve this.please help me, appreciate your all answers.here is my sample code

```
var options = {
     series: [{
         data: series.monthDataSeries1.prices
     }],
     chart: {
         height: 250,
         type: 'line',
         id: 'areachart-2'
     },
     annotations: {
         yaxis: [  {
             y: 8600,
             y2: 9000,
             borderColor: '#000',
             fillColor: '#FEB019',
             opacity: 0.3 
         }] 
     },
     dataLabels: {
         enabled: false
     },
     stroke: {
         curve: 'straight'
     },
     grid: {
         padding: {
             right: 30,
             left: 0
         }
     }, 
     labels: series.monthDataSeries1.dates,
     xaxis: {
         type: 'datetime',
     },
 };

 var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
 chart.render();
```

Comment: For getting real-time data in the application, you should need a SignalR library for real-time communication. Check out my [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77419478/updating-values-of-a-chart-in-a-razor-page/77428238?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C31.1801#77428238).